# Как получить доступ к интернету в приложении в AVD?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Дело в том, что доступ к интернету у эмулятора есть, браузер и прочие приложения имеют доступ в интернет. Но конкретно в моем приложении доступа нет. Я пытаюсь связаться с Firebase, но идет просто бесконечное ожидание. Если запустить apk моего приложения на реальном устройстве, то все работает. В чем может быть проблема? (compileSdkVersion 29)

Вот блок кода из манифеста:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: LogCat что говорит? там должны быть какие-то сообщения.

Comment: да все, получилось, я удалил приложение с эмулятора, перезапустил студию, и в эмуляторе выключил вайфай, включив LTE. В итоге заработало)